# Is it possible to determine if a matrix is not diagonalizable via row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose a matrix can be row reduced to the identity matrix, is this enough to say that it is not diagonalizable? If so, what theorem(s) or logic figures this out?

Comment: The identity matrix itself can be row-reduced to the identity matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ can be obtained from one another by a row operation, yet one is diagonal and the other not diagonalizable.

Note that row operations "destroy" the identification between domain and target, which is essential to the notion of diagonalizabilty.